# error resolving "mysite:80""/profile.php" ("") for "10.238.0.4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no such record

Tags: localhost, vpn

I use OpenServer and sometimes when I refresh site on my local machine next error occures

```
error resolving "mysite:80""/profile.php" ("") for "10.238.0.4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no such record
```

I found nothing about it in the internet so I am here. How can I avoid this error and what does it means?

Thank you

Answer (score 20):

I just needed to close VPN-connection in my browser

Answer (score 1):

In my case something similar happened to me.
When trying to access a site on my localhost from FireFox.

It showed me this message: "error resolving" localhost: 80 "" / canvasgroup / "(" ") for" 10.238.0.0 ": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no such record".

But I solved it by turning off a VPN plugin that I had active.